# Why is the abbreviation pp used to mean pages?

Tags: abbreviations, etymology

I read on https://english.stackexchange.com/a/117978/17712

> pp stands for pages

Why is the abbreviation *pp* used to mean *pages*?

---

I tried to search for the answer, but couldn't find the answer yet. I looked at:

- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pp
- https://capitalizemytitle.com/abbreviation-for-pages/
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pp
- https://thewordcounter.com/abbreviation-for-pages/

Comment: Historical questions about "why" the language is the way it is are outside the scope of this website. We answer questions about usage. [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is the place for that.

Comment: @gotube There is an [etymology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag with over 100 questions.

Comment: The page for the tag itself says at the top to ask on English Stack Exchange instead. If you've got a decent reason for asking it here, then add it to your question and tag me back, and I'll happily retract my downvote.

Comment: @gotube "The page for the tag itself says at the top to ask on English Stack Exchange instead" -> that's incorrect, it only suggests it.

Comment: It's still my opinion that this question doesn't belong on an English learner's question site, regardless of the wording. But since it's not officially against the rules, if you do a trivial edit and then tag me, I'll be able to revert my downvote.

Comment: @gotube done, thanks

Comment: I see 2 VTC "This question should include more details than have been provided here." Please tell me what I should add.

Comment: I wonder whether this might be on-topic elsewhere as other languages do use doubling to indicate plural (well, Spanish does anyway). I have no experience with the Linguistics stack though.

Answer (score 1):

'pp' as a plural abbreviation for 'pages' dates back just about to the dawn of printing I believe. Similarly 'ff' was used for 'folios' (a folio is both sides of a page, front and back, and was common at a time when people would only number folios and then say 'folio 10, recto (front)' or 'folio 10, verso (back)'.

That probably explains the logic of why it was 'pp' and not 'ps' or 'pgs'. The authors/scribes at this time thought primarily in Latin, and they were saying 'pagina' not 'page'. The plural of 'pagina' is 'paginae', but I guess somebody somewhere considered 'pp' and 'ff' a less confusing system than 'pe' (for paginae) and 'fi' (for folii). (Since Latin plural ending differing depending on both the declension and case, adding any single letter to indicate plural would probably be confusing).

Moreover the highly familiar but elaborate abbreviation system used by scribes at that time (and in some ways carried over into early printed books) had a convention of abbreviating a wide variety of Latin plurals to (eg) pp or ff.

So, 'ff' could be 'felices', 'filii', 'fratres'. 'pp' could be 'patres', 'pedes', 'pepetuum', 'provinciae' and much more ... almost at the whim of the scribe.

In other words, in the context of a Latin document, 'pp' would have been the least ambiguous way of indicating 'pages' via an abbreviation. It stuck, and here we are.

(Source for abbreviations is C. T. Martin, *The Record Interpreter*, London 1910, and [Capelli's *Dizionario Di Abbreviature*](https://archive.org/details/CappelliDizionarioDiAbbreviature/mode/2up) if you want a detailed look at the full horror of medieval scribal abbreviations.)